# problemas para realizar SELECT desde python con sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, base-de-datos, select, sqlite3

En el código todo está bien hasta que se ejecuta la función **consultar** debido a que poco después de la ejecución del esta parte aparece un error y no lo he podido resolver. (Es mi primera vez intentando hacer esto y realmente en la mayoría de sitios donde he buscado, la información n es mucho más avanzada y no logro comprender bien).

El error dece así: TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)

Este es todo el codigo:

```
import sqlite3

def insertar():
    db1 = sqlite3.connect("novelas.db")
    
    print("estas en la funcion insertar")

    nombre1 = input("escribe el titulo de la novela: ")
    autor1 = input("escribe el autor de al autor: ")
    year1 = str(input("digita el año de la novela: "))

    consulta = db1.cursor()

    strConsulta = "insert into tabla(nombre, autor, year) values ("+ nombre1 + "," + autor1 + "," + year1 + ")"
    print(strConsulta)
    consulta.close()
    db1.commit()
    db1.close()

insertar()

def consultar():
    db2 = sqlite3.connect("novelas.db")
    print("Estas en la funcion insertar 2")
    db2.row_factory = sqlite3.Row()#aqui esta parte del error
    consulta = db2.cursor()
    consulta.execute("select * from tabla")
    filas = consulta.fetchall()
    lista = []

    for fila in filas:
        s ={}
        s['nombre'] = fila['nombre']
        s['autor'] = fila['autor']
        s['year'] = str(fila['year'])
        lista.append(s)
    consulta.close()
    db2.close()
    return(lista)

def menu():
    opcion = input("\n seleccione la opcion deseada \n 1.inserta un valor \n 2. consular los valores de la tabla\n ")
    if opcion == "1":
        insertar()
        menu()
    elif opcion == "2" :
        lista_novela = consultar()
        for novela in lista_novela:
            print (novela["nombre"], novela["autor"], novela["year"])
        menu()

menu()
```

(El curso en el que vi esto es uno de "capacítate para el empleo").

Comment: quítale los paréntesis `db2.row_factory = sqlite3.Row`

Comment: gracias, ya lo probare